# Вывод текста из консоли в окно Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, gui

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться с Tkinter, возможен ли вывод всего текста который пишется в консоли в окно Tkinter? Если да то как это реализовать?

Comment: Вот решение на ваш вопрос https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12351786/how-to-redirect-print-statements-to-tkinter-text-widget

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Создаем объект-обертку над `Text`, который будет вести себя как файловый объект (будет поддерживать запись в него через метод `write`), и подменяем им объект стандартного вывода (`sys.stdout`) с помощью контекстного менеджера `redirect_stdout`:

```
import tkinter as tk
from contextlib import redirect_stdout


class TextWrapper:
    text_field: tk.Text

    def __init__(self, text_field: tk.Text):
        self.text_field = text_field

    def write(self, text: str):
        self.text_field.insert(tk.END, text)

    def flush(self):
        self.text_field.update()


root = tk.Tk()

text = tk.Text(root)
text.pack()

with redirect_stdout(TextWrapper(text)):  # подменяем объект sys.stdout на свой объект
    print("Hello!!!!")  # print внутри вызывает метод write объекта sys.stdout

print("Hello again")  # Вывод в консоль

root.mainloop()
```

Также такой псевдо-файловый объект можно просто указать через параметр `file` функции `print` и не делать подмену `sys.stdout`:

```
root = tk.Tk()

text = tk.Text(root)
text.pack()

print("Hello!!!!", file=TextWrapper(text))
```

[image: Скриншот]